# Telefone Conferencing API

Tags: phone-call

I am looking for an API to call phones (from server) and connect them to a telephone-conference.

Could you please recommend something?

Answer (score 2):

I would not call it an api but the first thing I would think about is installing an [asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) server and then calling asterisk scripts. Asterisk is a very mature telephone-(mostly everything you want) open source program. I don't know about your complete needs but I think it is worth a look.

A good starting point maybe the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk_%28PBX%29) page.

Answer (score 0):

[Hoiio Conference API](http://api.hoiio.com/voice_conference.html) can do that.

You can put up to 8 people in a conference rooms easily with a few lines of code.